# MySqli LIKE query not matching number of parameter

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The following query is resulting in the browser printing a

> "does not match number of parameters"

type of error.

Why is this happening?

When I replace with `LIKE '%".$country."%'` and get rid of the bind_param it does not bring up any errors.

```
$query = "
SELECT * from (    
    SELECT link
    FROM items
    WHERE countries LIKE '%?%'
    ORDER BY value DESC
    LIMIT 10   
) T ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
";
if ($statement = $mysqli->prepare($query))
{
    $statement->bind_param("s", $country);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();
    $statement->bind_result($link);
    $statement->fetch();
    $statement->free_result();
    $statement->close();
}
```

I'd like to prepare the statement instead of inserting raw data into the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%` must be part of the value :

```
$query = "
SELECT * from (    
    SELECT link
    FROM items
    WHERE countries LIKE ?
    ORDER BY value DESC
    LIMIT 10   
) T ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
";
if ($statement = $mysqli->prepare($query))
{
    $statement->bind_param("s","%".$Country."%");
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();
    $statement->bind_result($link);
    $statement->fetch();
    $statement->free_result();
    $statement->close();
}
```

Comment: works perfectly thanks! I'll accept when the timer allows me to :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like

```
$country = "%{$country}%";

$query = "
SELECT * from (    
    SELECT link
    FROM items
    WHERE countries LIKE ?
    ORDER BY value DESC
    LIMIT 10   
) T ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
";
if ($statement = $mysqli->prepare($query))
{
    $statement->bind_param("s", $country);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();
    $statement->bind_result($link);
    $statement->fetch();
    $statement->free_result();
    $statement->close();
}
```